# Invalid asset name supplied

Tags: ios, objective-c, idioms, function

I am trying to create an universal app that would display different images depending on the device. I am using this code so that the app could determine which image to display:`#define IMAGE (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad ?  @"Image_iPad.png" : @"Image-iPhone.png")`

For a button, the code would then look this: [Button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed: IMAGE] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

It works well, but now I have the following error each time the images are displayed on either device: CUICatalog: Invalid asset name supplied: (null), or invalid scale factor : 2.000000. Does this error come from the code, and is there a simple solution to this?

Comment: If you log the string your #define results in, what do you get?

Comment: Actually, I think it didn't come from this. The messages stopped happening when I replaced the lines [Button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; by [Button setImage:[[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:nil ofType:nil inDirectory:nil]] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; in all my code.